# Joining data from two Excel spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, spreadsheet

I currently have two Excel spreadsheets. One displays a list of people, many of whom are part of a certain organization. There's a column for Person ID, which they all have, and another column for Member ID, which only members of the organization have. The second spreadsheet contains all the contact information for the members, and has a Member ID column but nothing for Person ID. Is there a way to merge the data so that the second spreadsheet pulls over the corresponding Person IDs to match all the Member IDs?

I've currently got something like...

```
PERSON SPREADSHEET
Person ID     Name           Member ID
0001          John Smith     1234
0002          Jane Doe       5678
0003          Mike Jones     9012

MEMBER SPREADSHEET
Member ID     Active?      Last Visit
1234          Yes          5/01/2017
5678          Yes          5/05/2017
9012          Yes          5/10/2017
```

...And I want something like...

```
Member ID    Person ID    Active?    Last Visit
1234         0001         Yes        5/01/2017
5678         0002         Yes        5/05/2017
9012         0003         Yes        5/10/2017
```

Comment: Use MATCH, INDEX or VLOOKUP commands. Should be pretty straight forward and many examples how to use those 3 commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a sample for you [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbqpgcpifif3k0u/Joining%20data%20from%20two%20Excel%20spreadsheets.xlsx?dl=0).

Comment: Thanks! I think that's about the same method I ended up figuring out on my own, but it's great to see I'm on the right track.

Comment: That sounds great!!!